# why date is written differently in the output txt file?

Tags: r, date

I am writing a date variable `(A)` to a txt file but I found in the output file that the date is written differently in the txt file?

```
 head(A)
 [1] "2013-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2013-01-01 06:00:00 UTC" "2013-01-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2013-01-01 18:00:00 UTC"
 [5] "2013-01-02 00:00:00 UTC" "2013-01-02 06:00:00 UTC"
 write.table(A,file="date.txt")
```

In the output file `date.txt` it is like this:

```
      "A" 
     "1" 1356998400 
     "2" 1357020000
```

Comment: Try `A <- data.frame(V1=A); write.table(A, file='date.txt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
write.table(as.character(A),file="date.txt")
```